# Copy 2d array which have different columns in c

Tags: c

I want to write a function that copies an array of different column numbers. My current code can only copy arrays with a fixed number of columns. How can I modify my code so that functions can copy arrays with the different numbers of columns?

My idea is to provide different column number information in the parameter list, but I am not sure how to implement it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// simple program to copy a 2d array of numbers

int **array_copy2d(int **src, int rows, int cols) {
    // allocate
    int **result = malloc(sizeof(int*) * rows);
    if (result == NULL) {
      return NULL;
    }

    // copies from src to dest array.
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        // allocate a row
        result[row] = malloc(sizeof(int) * cols);
        if (result[row] == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        // copy a row. 
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            result[row][col] = src[row][col];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

// driver code for array copy
int main(void) {
    // declare and build 2d array
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 2;
    int row0[] = { 1, 2 };
    int row1[] = { 3, 4 };
    int row2[] = { 5, 6 };
    int *vals[3];

    // build vals
    vals[0] = row0;
    vals[1] = row1;
    vals[2] = row2;

    // destination array
    int **val_copy;

    // copy
    val_copy = array_copy2d(vals, rows, cols);
    // check if malloc worked
    if (val_copy == NULL) {
        printf("allocation error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // test
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            printf("%d ", val_copy[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Test sample:

```
1  2
3  4
5  6
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: What makes you think that "My current code can only copy arrays with a fixed number of columns." What happens otherwise?

Comment: @Yunnosch  Because currently the code only accepts the number of pre-set columns.

Comment: What are the symptoms of that? Can you demonstrate them in a [mre]?

Comment: There are no 2D arrays in your code, only 1D pointer array look-up tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
int rows, cols; 
scanf("%d%d", &rows,&cols);

int **vals = malloc(sizeof(int*)*rows);
for(int row=0; row<rows; row++){
   vals[row] = malloc(sizeof(int*)*cols);
   for(int col=0; col<cols; col++){
      scanf("%d", &vals[row][col]);
   }
}

int **val_copy = malloc(sizeof(int*)*rows);

val_copy = array_copy2d(vals, rows, cols);

if (val_copy == NULL) {
  printf("allocation error\n");
  return 1;
}

for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
   for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
     printf("%d ", vals[row][col]);
   }printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code can copy a submatrix: the number of rows and columns in the destination matrix must be less or equal to the number of rows and columns in the source matrix.

You can modify the code to allow for larger numbers if you pass the dimensions of the source and destination matrices separately.

If you want to handle jagged arrays, ie: if the number of columns in the source matrix varies from one row to the next, the row widths must be passed separately, as an array.

Here is a modified version for arbitrary sizes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// simple program to copy a 2d array of numbers

int **array_copy2d(int row1, int col1, int **src, int rows, int cols) {
    // allocate
    int **result = calloc(sizeof(int*), rows1);
    if (result == NULL) {
      return NULL;
    }

    for (int row1 = 0; row < rows1; row++) {
        // allocate a row
        result[row] = calloc(sizeof(int), cols1);
        if (result[row] == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    // copies from src to dest array.
    if (rows > rows1)
        rows = rows1;
    if (cols > cols1)
        cols = cols1;
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        // copy a row. 
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            result[row][col] = src[row][col];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// driver code for array copy
int main(void) {
    // declare and build 2d array
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 2;
    int row0[] = { 1, 2 };
    int row1[] = { 3, 4 };
    int row2[] = { 5, 6 };
    int *vals[3] = { row0, row1, row2 };

    // destination array
    int **val_copy;

    // copy
    val_copy = array_copy2d(2, 4, vals, rows, cols);
    // check if malloc worked
    if (val_copy == NULL) {
        printf("allocation error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // test
    for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
            printf("%d ", val_copy[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 0 0
3 4 0 0
```